# My app always crashes whole phone(Samsung Galaxy S2 rooted)

Tags: android, crash, galaxy, samsung-mobile

My app works perfectly well on LG-P690 and on all virtual devices I tried but when I tested it on my friends rooted samsung s2 it works for a while until it crashes the whole phone (a hard reset is needed). As I said, it never crashed on my own phone no mater how long I used it or on the emulator and I keep testing to see if I don't use too much heap memory(I never do).

What do you think causes an app to crash a whole phone like that? What should I be looking for?

Comment: Did you check Logcat ?

Comment: taken from the Android-dev channel in freenode: http://imgur.com/jacoj

Comment: I did on the devices that didn't crash. I'll check logcat and post what I find when I get my hands on that samsung. I just thought there were some usual reasons for phone crashes that I could learn about.